# How do you create ModuleCatalog from Xaml?

Tags: prism-4

I'm using Unity for my IoC container and in my bootstrapper I have this code:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
  return Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(
    new Uri("modulecatalog.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

and I created an xml file named "modulecatalog.xaml" with this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Modularity:ModuleCatalog
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
  xmlns:Modularity="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism">

</Modularity:ModuleCatalog>
```

And I'm already getting errors in the xaml saying that Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity could not be found and Modularity:ModuleCatalog was not found.

This is extremely frustrating. I have Microsoft.Practices.Prism included in my project. The code in my Bootstrapper compiles so obviously Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog does exist. But even more strangeness, if I change my CreateModuleCatalog function to this:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity;

...

protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
  return ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(
    new Uri("modulecatalog.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

It says that CreateFromXaml doesn't exist on ModuleCatalog. It has no problem finding ModuleCatalog, but that function apparently does not exist if I don't type out the full namespace every time. WTF is going on?

Comment: Funny. I am currently searching for the same =). I post here if I have found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly resolve the ModuleCatalogtype like this and it should work

```
protected override Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
   return Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml( new Uri( "Modules.xaml", UriKind.Relative ) );
}
```

The Errors with not found the Modularity:ModuleCatalog are the same for me but the Applications runs well.

Ah I nearly forgot. Set the modules.xaml file to resource

Comment: You're saying you still get errors in your xaml file asying that Modularity:ModuleCatalog was not found but it still works anyway?

Comment: Exactly. My Modules.xaml gets parsed correctly bei the ReadFromXaml Method and my modules are being loaded in my app. Just make sure your dll's and namespaces in this File are correct

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this. I eventually resolved this by the following:

**Setup:**
Within your shell, you should have your regions defined:

```
<Window x:Class="Prism101.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainContent" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Step 1: Add a reference to your module project / assembly.**

**Step 2: Declare a module within the Module Catalog:**
This is will be within your module project.

```
<Modularity:ModuleCatalog 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:Modularity="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition">

    <Modularity:ModuleInfo 
         Ref="Prism101.Modules.Core.xap"
         ModuleName="CoreModule" 
         ModuleType="Prism101.Modules.Core.CoreModule, Prism101.Modules.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
     />

</Modularity:ModuleCatalog>
```

**Step 3: Implement your module:**
Notice how the framework will initialize your RegionManager and UnityContainer for you.
Also note that the "WelcomeView" is a usercontrol that gets mapped to the maincontent region of the client's shell.

```
namespace Prism101.Modules.Core
{
    public class CoreModule : IModule
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer container;
        private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

        public CoreModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            this.container = container;
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            var view = new WelcomeView();
            regionManager.AddToRegion("MainContent", view);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4: Implement Bootstrapper:**
In the CreateModuleCatalog method, identify the name of the assembly that your catalog module is in as well as it's directory path.

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        var shell = new MainWindow();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = shell;

        return shell;
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        var assemblyName = "Prism101.Modules.Core";
        var filePath = "ModuleCatalog.xaml";
        var uriPath = string.Format("/{0};component/{1}", assemblyName, filePath);

        var uri = new Uri(uriPath, UriKind.Relative);
        var moduleCatalog = Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(uri);

        return moduleCatalog;
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:**
After reviewing these steps, one should be able to run the application and observe the results of bootstrapping a prism app with a module getting loaded.

**NOTE:**
Please feel free to provide feedback on how I could've articulated this better.